# grunt: how to detect if file is saved to uglify all of my js files

Tags: gruntjs, task-runner-explorer

I am trying to detect if some js is saved to uglify my js files or my css files.

I am having this code in GruntFile.js:

```
/// <binding ProjectOpened='uglify' />
module.exports = function (grunt) {
    grunt.initConfig({

        uglify: {
            bundle: {
                files: { 'Scripts/boooo.min.js': 'Scripts/bootstrap.js' }
            }
        },
        watch: {
            js: {
                files: ['Scripts/**/*.js'],
                tasks: ['uglify']
            }
        }
    });

    // Next one would load plugins
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');


    // Here is where we would define our task
    grunt.registerTask('default', ['watch:js']);


};
```

My Task Runner Explorer is:

[image]

My package json is:

```
{
  "name": "something",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "test",
  "main": "index.html",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "^0.4.5",
    "grunt-bower-task": "^0.4.0",
    "grunt-contrib-copy": "^0.8.0",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "^0.9.1",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "^0.6.1",
    "install": "^0.1.8",
    "jshint-stylish": "^2.0.1",
    "npm": "^2.13.4"
  }
}
```

How can I detect if it is saved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {
    grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
        watch: {
            scripts: {
                files: ['scripts/**/*.js'],
                tasks: ['uglify']
            }
        },
        uglify: {
            my_target: {
                options: {
                    beautify: false
                },
                files: {
                    '/Scripts/app.min.js': ['scripts/**/*.js']
                }
            }
        }
    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');

    grunt.registerTask('default', ['uglify:my_target', 'watch']);
};
```